# How to return 2 dimension array in C++

Tags: c++

I have a segmentationfault at the line :

```
cout <<  b[0][0];
```

Could someone tell me what should I do to fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int** gettab(int tab[][2]){
   return (int**)tab;
}

int main() {
   int a[4][2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
   int ** b = gettab(a);
   cout <<  b[0][0];
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 2-dimensional array is not the same thing as an array of pointers, which is how `int**` is interpreted.  Change the return type of gettab.

```
int* gettab(int tab[][2]){
   return &tab[0][0];
}

int main() {
  int a[4][2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
  int* b = gettab(a);
  cout << b[0]; // b[row_index * num_cols + col_index]
  cout << b[1 * 2 + 0]; // the 1 from {1, 0}
}
```

Or:

```
int (*gettab(int tab[][2]))[2] {
  return tab;
}
// or:
template<class T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
identity<int(*)[2]>::type gettab(int tab[][2]) {
  return tab;
}

int main() {
  int a[4][2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
  int (*b)[2] = gettab(a);
  cout << b[0][0];
}
```

Comment: this line : 
int (*)[2] gettab2(int tab[][2]){
doesn't compile. I have the error : 
main.cpp|14|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token|
main.cpp|14|error: expected initializer before ‘gettab2’|

Comment: Should be 

int (* gettab(int tab[][2])) [2]

I recommend not returning arrays though :)

Comment: @Roger The downvote wasn't from me, but your second solution looks strange to me and doesn't compile with my compiler (VS 2005), does this work for you?

Comment: My fault on the syntax, fixed and provided an easier to read alternative.  (A typedef of `int(*)[2]` works too.)

Comment: The downvote was actually before I had the code sample in there, which I edited in within the first 5 minutes.

Comment: int (*gettab(int tab[][2]))[2] {
  return tab;
}
is working but wow, it looks horrible :)
Tomorrow I'll try to use Boost instead. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: unknown: I agree that there's probably a better solution to what you're really doing, but since you've not said what you're really doing all I can do is fix the example you put in the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Being c++, rather than c, there are [much](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) [better](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) ways of handling arrays of all sorts, and passing them around.

Comment: another good link: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.11 " Why shouldn't my Matrix class's interface look like an array-of-array?"

Comment: @danio but my matrix class's interface does look like that, oh no D:

Answer (score 2):

The type of `tab` without square brackets is not actually `int **`. It is actually `int (*)[2]`. When you apply two `[]` operators to the resulting pointer, you end up dereferencing the first value in your array, `0`, as a NULL pointer. Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*foo)[2];

foo gettab(int tab[][2]){
   return tab;
}

int main() {
   int a[4][2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
   foo b = gettab(a);
   cout <<  b[0][0];
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your seg fault us because you pass in an "int*" effectively.  A 2D array is not a double pointer ...

You are best off using a pointer that is "x*y" in size and addressing it without the 2 dimensions ... the code will end up the same anyway as the compiler will just generate the same code you would have to write more explicitly anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

a 2 diminsional array isn't the same thing as an array of pointers. a 2 dimensional array is just a pointer to a hunk of memory that you have told the compiler to let you access as a 2 dimensional array

```
int* gettab(int tab[][2]) {   
   return (int*)tab;
}

int main() {   
   int a[4][2] = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};   
   int* b = gettab(a);   
   cout <<  b[0 + 2*0];   
   return 0;
}
```

will do what you want.  But I wonder if you really need to be trying to return a 2 dimensional array from a function in the first place.  Perhaps a less made-up example if what you are trying to do would be helpful?

edit: fixed missing *2 in the calculation [0 + (sizeof(int)*2)*0].
edit again:  well that was dumb.  the multiplication of the column size of 2 by the size of an int is automatic in this case. sizeof(int) removed.

Comment: What exactly is `sizeof(int)` doing in `b[0 + sizeof(int)*0]`?